# why the r in rgb value is not correct when converting rgb to hsl in colorsys package

Tags: python, numpy, colors, rgb, hsl

```
import colorsys
print(colorsys.rgb_to_hls(92/255, 137/255, 78/255))
```

> [0.29378531 0.42156863 0.2744186]

Saturation (S),Lightness (L) is correct(according this [website](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.html)), but Hue should 106, I am not sure where is problem?

Comment: Why? Its description says "... Coordinates in all of these color spaces are floating point values. In the YIQ space, the Y coordinate is between 0 and 1, but the I and Q coordinates can be positive or negative. In all other spaces, the coordinates are all between 0 and 1." And 360 * 0.29378531 yields 106 (-ish).

Comment: Why does your title say the `r` is not correct, but your question says that the hue is wrong?

Comment: As you scale the input, you should scale the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `colorsys.rgb_to_hls` is expressed in parts per unit (between 0 and 1):

```
106/360=0.294
```

You can see the permitted values of the functions of `colorsys` in the following picture:

[image]

Comment: @usr2564301 This is actually an ill-advised nitpick. 0.294 **is** a percentage, as well as 29.4/100 and 29.4 % (which is just a shorthand notation for 29.4/100). David, you can of course say percentage if you deem it more understandable